# Where can I watch My Hero Academia Season 4 English dub for free?

Tags: my-hero-academia, streaming-sites

My Hero Academia Season 4 (English dub and Japanese) used to be free on Funimation, but yesterday I checked and found out that almost all, except a few, can't be watched in ANY language for Season 4. I remember that before Season 4 was free, it was only for premium for a while, so maybe if I wait for some more time, it will become free again? Or is there another site I can use to see the My Hero Academia English dub?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Hulu is a good one, they offer 7 day free trials and that is enough time to finish season 4 of you watch about 5h a day.

Answer (score 0):

Anime Planet is both legal and free.

Comment: I just checked it out, apparently, it doesn't have an English dub :/